# Kibana 4: Can't do wildcard query with dot in field value

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I have a analyzed field hostname and a not_analyzed field hostname.raw.

I'm trying to query a few hosts that have a dot in the field value, like

AP.MO.HALL-01
AP.MO.2FLOOR-01

When I try to query `hostname:AP.MO.*`, it also returns hosts with the value AP.MOOCA.HALL
When I try to query using the field that isn't analyzed, I get no results at all: `hostname.raw:AP.MO.*`

How can I make Kibana respect the dot before the wildcard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get a similar issue resolved by using a RegEx query, and escaping the periods within the hostname.

Looking at your example, something similar to the following should work:

`hostname: /.*AP\.MO\..*/`

Comment: Thank you for that.